# strtok() in c - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

Everytime I try to use strtok() i get an segmentation fault. Don't know why- I'm new to C.

Here is my code:

```
#include "shellutils.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char input[150];

    while(1) {
        prompt();
        fgets(input, 150, stdin);

        char *fst_tkn = strtok(input, " ");

        printf("%s", fst_tkn);


        if(feof(stdin) != 0 || input == NULL) {
            printf("Auf Bald!\n");
            exit(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should check if `fst_tkn` is not `NULL` even after the first call to `strtok`.

Comment: btw, return `EXIT_FAILURE` instead of arbitrary values, it's declared in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Is this code correct?  You should be `#include <string.h>` to pick up strtok correctly, at least on Linux.  I can get a similar seg fault when the line is `strtok(input, ' ');` (note single quotes) but it works for me as typed above.

Comment: when posting source code, please post the OS on which you ran it. Also, what is shellutils.h, and where is it located? What version of C is this. I'm used to having to declare pointers up front before executable code begins.

Comment: good to know. it just works now thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the code:

```
char *fst_tkn = strtok(input, " ");
printf("%s", fst_tkn);
```

If your `input` variable is empty, or contains only spaces, then `fst_tkn` will be set to `NULL`. Then, when you try and print that as a string, all bets are off.

You can see that in the following code by adjusting the values tou give to `input`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void) {
    char input[] = "";
    char *fst_tkn = strtok (input, " ");
    printf ("fst_tkn is %s\n", (fst_tkn == NULL) ? "<<null>>" : fst_tkn);
    return 0;
}
```